# chart formatting lost when save as xlsx in NPOI

Tags: excel, xlsx, npoi

I have a template xlsx, called "book3.xlsx" that contains a pre-formatted chart. All I want to do is to read my template xlsx and modify some cells and write out the a xlsx ("test.xlsx")

A strange thing happens here, if i open the result xlsx the format of the chart has changed... It has different coloring, axis is missing etc. When I used xls file format it was fine, but we should use xlsx. Anyone noticed this issue?

```
        var file = new FileStream(@"book3.xlsx", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        var workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

        using (var fs = new FileStream(@"test.xlsx", FileMode.Create))
        {
            workbook.Write(fs);
        }
```

Comment: You haven't specified version of NPOI you're using, so it's kinda hard to make assumptions. This can be bug local to exact version you're using. Probably updating your NPOI to the latest version will help.

Comment: It is the latest version, at the moment 2.1.3, sorry....

Comment: Finally we dropped npoi, aspose cells was working fine....